# Giving a div a style on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

applying a class to an element only when clicked

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: So it looks like you already know how to apply some styling with js, why haven't you implemented it for the `clickFunction`? Or the problem is with applying the class to the element?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to apply the .boom/.safe class to the element when clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make 2 different click functions. One for trap and one for the rest.

For that you need to know which ones are the other ( safe ones ). See `otherDivsIds` in the below code. You find the other `id's` using the filter function in the `idArray` and then loop through them ( with forEach or something else ) and add event listeners to each of them.

I would also suggest to ' swap ' the naming of the variables trapBox and trapId. Vice versa would be better

See code below

```js
var idArray = ['one','two','three','four'];
var trapBox = idArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * idArray.length)];
var trapId= document.getElementById(trapBox);

trapId.addEventListener('click', boomClickFunction, false);
var otherDivsIds = idArray.filter(id => id !== trapBox);
otherDivsIds.forEach(id => {
 safeBox =  document.getElementById(id);
  safeBox.addEventListener('click', safeClickFunction, false)
})


var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(ticker, 5000);
function ticker() {
  document.getElementById('timesUp').innerHTML = "Time's up!";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
} 


function boomClickFunction() {
 this.classList.add('boom')

}
function safeClickFunction() {
 this.classList.add('safe')
}
```

```css
 div {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: green;
   margin: 20px;
   float: left;
 }

 .boom {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .safe {
   background-color: lightblue;
 }

 #timesUp {
   color: white;
 }
```

```html
<div id='one'>

</div>
<div id='two'>

</div>
<div id='three'>

</div>
<div id='four'>

</div>
<span id="timesUp">

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to an element by using `classList.add('classToBeAdded')`.

In your case, you could put it in your `clickFunction`:

```
trapId.classList.add('boom');
```